# Perl string replacing quotes causes the browser to hang

Tags: string, perl, replace, double-quotes

I'm reading in some data and need to remove the double quotes. I'm using

```
$myArray[$i] =~ tr/"//d;
```

and although that works, when it gets to a particular element in the array, it hangs the browser. that element is:

```
"earnings":"{\"29262\":\"8.0595\"}"
```

I basically just need to get rid of the quotes, brackets, and slashes so it would look like **earnings:29262:8.0595** so I can better deal with the data.

Comment: Are you parsing JSON?

Comment: Use an existing JSON parser (e.g. Cpanel::JSON::XS) instead of trying to create your own.

Comment: `"earnings":"{\"29262\":\"8.0595\"}"` - this is not  string, a string could be this one `"\"earnings":"{\"29262\":\"8.0595\"}\""` Can you provide your real string?

Comment: Not using JSON, just extracting the data I'm given. Didn't know this was a JSON format actually. this will be a CGI on the web. I'll have to see if that parser is available.

Comment: As others have said, it looks like this was intended to be JSON data. Of course you're not obliged to treat it as such, but you haven't shown a valid Perl string so it's impossible to even guess what a solution may be. Is this within CGI code? Please show a Perl program that reproduces the problem, including the definition of `@myArray` and the code you have used to dump its contents

Comment: I don't see how malformed data could hang a browser, but perhaps I'm not being sufficiently imaginative. Are you simply experiencing the page becoming unresponsive, or do you have evidence that there is an endless JavaScript loop? Does it work if you remove the `tr///`? You say that you want to remove the quotes, brackets and slashes, but your code removes only double quotes. How about removing all that you *don't* want with `tr/0-9A-Za-z.:/cd`?

Comment: When I set up a loop to remove the quotes from all the data, it will hang at the point where it hits this specific array element. I know because the browswer will "load" to halfway then stall and I'll get an error eventually that says it's using too much memory. If I limit the loop to run to just prior that element, it will finish properly and not hang. Code is very simple... '
my $data = <REG>;

close(REG);

my @myArray = split(',', $data);

for ($i=0; $i <= @myArray.length; $i++) {
 $myArray[$i] =~ tr/"//d;
 print "$myArray[$i]<p>\n";
}
'

Comment: data comes in like this. I have it save as a text file for testing...   {"product_id":526280,"price":9.01,"country":"US","currency":"USD","sale_gross":9.01,"p_tax_amount":0,"p_fee":0.9505,"coupon_savings":0,"earnings":"{\"29262\":\"8.0595\"}","order_id":3188422,"p_coupon":"","p_used_price_override":true,"passthrough":"Example passthrough","p_quantity":1,"quantity":1}

Comment: `@myArray.length` is not valid Perl

Comment: I changed it to my $size = @myArray;

Comment: *"I changed it to `my $size = @myArray`"* ***Please always post your real code.*** It is impossible to help you to debug code that you are constantly modifying.

Comment: @MattJacob Just to be nitpicky, it's actually valid Perl, it just doesn't do what was expected. Perl interprets it as `scalar(@myArray) . length($_)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your regex, it's down to how you've written the loop

```
for ($i=0; $i <= @myArray.length; $i++)
```

If, for example, your array contained 5 elements, the loop will allow `$i` to equal 5 which equates to the 6th element in the array. Because of this when you do the regex on `$myArray[5]` it will populate it with a value and that will alter the size of the array. And because the size of the array has increased, the loop won't terminate and will continue growing the array until you run out of memory.

If you're going to use `<=` in such a loop you want to use `$#myArray` to get the highest index in use, like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $#myArray; $i++)
```

It looks like you've fixed your problem by luck, because you've stored the size of the array in `$size` and presumably have re-written the loop like

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $size; $i++)
```

so it will create just one extra element in the array and stop. If you're going to use the size of the array, you want to use `<` like this.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++)
```

Comment: yes, i did rewrite the loop, but when i set the loop to stop at one less than the one that gave me problems, it did not hang. when i set it explicitly to the one that caused the problem, it would hang (i was not setting the array length). once i escaped the quote it worked fine. i have it working also with $size now too. thanks for all the help, everyone. i appreciate it. i'm not a programmer so i know i can ask some dumb questions sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

guess I just needed to escape the double quote. this seems to work:

```
$myArray[$i] =~ tr/\"//d;
```

Comment: That isn't necessary unless your Perl code is being executed in a strange way, perhaps via a call to the shell? Please resolve this, as many people will arrive here hoping for a solution to a similar problem. Please provide additional information, especially code and data, by editing your question. It is unreadable in comments.